# In DB2 String replace

Tags: sql, string, db2

I have 2 fields in my DB2 database: DATE and TIME. DATE is string (8/25/2013), DATE is timestamp (1/1/1970 7:00:00 AM). I want to write a sql to replace 1/1/1970 with 8/25/2103. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: is that 2013 for the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to cast your string to a date, using the `DATE` function

```
DATE(DATE)
```

Where you see that's it's a bad idea to name your columns with existing function names...

Then combining the `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, and `TIME` function (again really unclear with your field names, but...)

```
TIMESTAMP(DATE(DATE), TIME(TIME))
```

Will give you a timestamp where the date part is coming from the DATE field, and the time part from the TIME field

See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html) and [that](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000859.htm)

Comment: Why are you casting types? What is gained?

Answer (score 0):

After casting to a DATE format, adding the difference between those two absolute dates should work -

```
UPDATE <table-name> 
SET DATE= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'1/1/1970','8/25/2013'),DATE)
WHERE DATE < '1/2/1970' AND DATE>='1/1/1970'
```

More on [DATEADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) and [DATEDIFF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)
Also, it is recommended to not use 'DATE' as a column name as it is a reserved [edit] function name.